# Is kernel mode dependent on CS?

Tags: linux, kernel

How does os detect if the present code is being run in kernel mode or user mode? Is it inherent to code section i.e., a specific code section can be run only in kernel mode(or user mode)? Or can a code section be run in both kernel and user mode?

EDIT: to be specific My question is protetection rings set in  DPL (Descriptor Privilage Level) inate to Code Section?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to be more specific. Read about [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), this might be what you're looking for. Unix and Linux too has traditionally used only two levels: one for the kernel and one for user.

Comment: My question is protetection rings set in DPL (Descriptor Privilage Level) inate to Code Section?

Comment: ["The segment selector must be located in one of the segment registers. That selector consists of a 2-bit Requested Privilege Level (RPL), a 1-bit Table Indicator (TI), and a 13-bit index."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Detailed_Segmentation_Unit_Workflow)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, So the current privilage level depends on my current code segment which means a specific code section cannot be run in user and kernel Mode. Please Correct me if I wrong.